# All possible factorisations of a number

Tags: prime-factorization

Is there a method for finding all possible n-factor factorisations of a number? For example, if all possible 2-factor factorisations of 90 (up to order) are:

```
1 × 90
2 × 45
3 × 30
5 × 18
6 × 15
9 × 10
```

How do I discover all the remaining 3-factor, 4-factor, etc, factorisations (until I am left with purely prime factorisations)? Do I simply need to grind through them mechanically, or is there a more elegant method for finding them? (I need the actual factorisations, not simply the total number of those factorisations).

Comment: For two factors , this is easy. You just need the divisors. For three, let run $d$ over the divisors of the given number and apply the method for two factors for each cofactor. Recursively , this can be extended to more and more factors.

Comment: @Peter Your comment assumes that repeated factors are permissible.  I question this.  For example, I *speculate* that while the OP (i.e. original poster) would consider $~1 \times 5 \times 18~$ to be a legitimate $3$-factor of $~90,~$ the OP would not consider $~1 \times 1 \times 5 \times 18~$ to be a legitimate $4$-factor of $~90.~$  Assuming (perhaps wrongly) that my speculation is accurate, you then have the open question: does the OP consider $~2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5~$ to be a legitimate $4$-factor of $~90~?~$

Comment: @user2661923 I don't see your point. Whether we include redundant $1$-factors or not is trivial. Either way, the core of the decomposition is the factorization.

Comment: @Jam Assume that repeated factors are prohibited and re-consider Peter's comment.  The way that I interpret his recursion algorithm, there is no safeguard against repeated roots.  For example, $~36 = 2 \times 18,~$ and $~18 = 2 \times 9,~$ so his list of $~3$-factor factorizations of $~36~$ would include $~2 \times 2 \times 9,~$ which may run counter to the OP's intentions.  As a separate issue is $~1 \times 1 \times 36~$ to be considered a legitimate $3$-factor factorization of $~36~?~$  ...see next comment

Comment: @Jam If $~2 \times 2 \times 18~$ is not considered to be a legitimate $3$-factor factorization of $~36,~$ then I speculate that Peter's whole approach is problematic.  Alternatively, if it is to be considered legitimate, but the $~1 \times 1 \times 36~$ $3$-factor factorization of $~36~$ is not to be considered legitimate, then I speculate that Peter's approach is do-able but requires extra attention to eliminate such expressions as $~1 \times 1 \times 36.$

Comment: @user2661923 I don't understand why you are excluding decompositions with repeated factors.

Comment: @Jam Because it is very common for a question to be posted on MathSE that omits a constraint that was intended by the OP (i.e. original poster).  I am not assuming that the OP intends to exclude such decompositions.  However, I am assuming that it is very plausible that the OP does intend to exclude such decompositions.  In particular, I seriously question whether the OP would consider $~1 \times 1 \times 36~$ to be a legitimate $3$-factor factorization of $~36.~$  As far as $~2 \times 2 \times 18,~$ I think it is anybody's guess whether the OP regards this as legitimate.

Comment: @user2661923 Where is the problem ? We can simply omit factorizations if they are not legitimate , and count the rest. Whether there is a nice formula for the number of possibilities , is another story.

Comment: @Peter "...and count the rest."  Unless I am mistaken, you end up simply manually counting the possible $~k$-factor factorizations.  For example, consider enumerating the $~3$-factor factorizations of $~90 = 2 \times 3^2 \times 5.~$  Now, when $~d = 2,~$ you then compute the $2$-factor factorizations of $~45.~$  However, when $~d = 3,~$ when computing the $2$-factor factorizations of $~30,~$  you must not allow either the second or third factor to equal $~3.~$ ...see next comment

Comment: @Peter When $~n = 90,~$ the enumeration is not that difficult.  However, in the general case of the prime factorization of $~n~$ being given by $$n = \prod_{i=1}^r \left(p_i\right)^{a_i},$$ the recursion approach that you have suggested becomes nightmarish to implement.

Comment: @user2661923 I never claimed that this approach is efficient , for something like $200!$ , it probably does not work well. But 1. the author did nowhere mention that he/she needs this methods for huge numbers with a huge number of divisors 2. My simple method can easily be improved to avoid many of the duplicates or illegitimate factorizations and 3. since the author wants the factorizations , we must enumerate them anyway.

Comment: You could as well argue that integer factorization is hard but I assume that the prime factorization is known.

Comment: @Peter Consider (for example) $~n = 2^5 \times 3^4 \times 5^3,~$ and $~k = 4.~$  Also "2. ...can easily be improved..." : if you mean eliminating all factorizations with duplicate factors, I question how easy this would be.  Further "3. ... we must enumerate them anyway." I surmise that the original poster is looking for a closed form computation, based on $~n, ~k~$ and (perhaps) the prime factorization of $~n.$

Comment: @Peter re last comment, a reasonable alternative is a formula iteratively computed via recursion, rather than a closed form computation.  However, even with numbers as small as $~n = 2^5 \times 3^4 \times 5^3~$ and $~k = 4,~$ recursion would be very difficult to implement.

Comment: I count 10 possible (integer, up to order, and non-trivial - the latter which I should have made clear) factorisations, namely five 2-factor factorisations: 2 x 45, 3 x 30, 5 x 18, 6 x 15 and 9 x 10; four 3-factor factorisations: 2 x 3 x 15, 2 x 5 x 9, 3 x 3 x 10, and 3 x 5 x 6; and one 4-factor factorisation: 2 x 3 x 3 x 5. I'm not sure where @TonyK gets 12 from (that seems to be the number of factors, including trivial factors). What I'd like to know if there is an elegant method for determining the 10 factorisations (again, according to my calculations - I'm new to maths) listed above.

Answer (score -2):

$1$ is not an interesting factor, so you can remove the first entry in your list, to leave:

```
2 × 45
3 × 30
5 × 18
6 × 15
9 × 10
```

The first entry gives you the smallest prime factor, $2$. Now go through the rest of the list, dividing one number from each entry by $2$, to get:

```
3 × 15
5 × 9
3 × 15
9 × 5
```

The smallest number here is $3$. So remove the first and third entries, and go through the rest of the list, dividing one number from each entry by $3$, to get:

```
5 × 3
3 × 5
```

The smallest number is again $3$ so remove that to leave yourself with $5$.

So the prime factorisation of $90$ is $2\times 3^2\times 5$. And the exponents of the primes are $1,2,1$, so there are $2\times 3\times 2=12$ factorisations in total.